# ¿Cómo crear un placeholder label?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, material-design

Cómo crear un `placeholder label`  [tipo la plataforma wix](https://users.wix.com/signin?overrideLocale=es&loginDialogContext=login&referralInfo=HEADER&postLogin=https:%2F%2Fes.wix.com%2Fmy-account%2Fsites%2F&postSignUp=https:%2F%2Fes.wix.com%2Fnew%2Fvertical%3FreferralAdditionalInfo%3Dheader&originUrl=https:%2F%2Fes.wix.com%2F) si se puede observar al dar clic en el `input` **Email** el `placeholder` no desaparece si no se encima en la parte superior.

Al copiar al elemento del formulario **Wix**, se puede observar que no existe en el formulario `input` la función `placeholder`

```
<input autofocus="" default-email="" name="email" ng-attr-wix-mail-validator="{{!$ctrl.novalidateEmail()}}" ng-model="$ctrl.email" required="" type="email" class="ng-pristine ng-scope md-input ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" id="input_0" wix-mail-validator="true" style="">
```

Cómo puedo añadir aquel efecto en Mi código

```css
.form-two {
outline: none;
color: #212121;
font-size: 13px;
border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
background: none;
width: 100%;
padding: 1.2em 1.8em;
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="container">
<div class="wrp">
    <h2>ENTRE AQUÍ.</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
     <!-- class="form-one"  -->
     <div class="left">
       <input type="text" class="form-two" name="First Name" placeholder="Nombre">
     </div>
   <div class="right">
     <input type="text" class="form-two" name="Last Name" placeholder="Apellidos">
   </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un componente de [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html) conocido como **Text Field** y se puede crear en efecto con un poco de html y css. Este es un ejemplo tomado de CodePen:

```css
* { box-sizing:border-box; }

.container { 
  margin:30px auto 0; 
  padding:10px 50px 50px;
}

.group { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:45px; 
}

input {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}

input:focus {
  outline:none;
}

label {
  color:#999; 
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}

.bar {
  position:relative; 
  display:block;
  width:300px; 
}

.bar:before, .bar:after {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:#5264AE; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}

.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  width:100px; 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
 from { background:#5264AE; }
  to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Nombre</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Shaz por el ejemplo ;)

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacer algo parecido pero con un input del tipo email. Es para una subscripcion al newsletter de una pagina ecommerce.